# Is it possible to place an HTML element in multiple CSS Grid areas?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I was wondering if there is any possibility to place one markup element multiple times in a page, without duplicating it. For example:

```css
.grid {
  grid-template-areas: 
  "hero hero hero hero" 
  "menu menu menu menu" 
  "banner banner banner banner"
  "sidebar content content content" 
  "banner banner banner banner"
  "footer footer footer footer";
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="menu"></div>
  <div class="hero"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
  <div class="promo-banner"></div>
</div>
```

So let's say I'd like that banner section to be visible multiple times in a page but only write it once inside html.

Comment: use `content:''`?  Other than that probably need a server side language that allows you to include other files so you could do it as a separate file and include it where you need it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No...this is not possible.

Elements are placed once and once only.

Also, grid areas can only be placed once as a **single rectangular area**.

So this is invalid:

```
.grid {
  grid-template-areas: 
  "hero hero hero hero" 
  "menu menu menu menu" 
  "banner banner banner banner" /*<== is invalid as also defined below */
  "sidebar content content content" 
  "banner banner banner banner" 
  "footer footer footer footer";
}
```

Comment: @AlexandruD.Gatea Please mark this as accepted (green check to the left from this answer) if it helped you.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for your answer!